# Need to save XML document from Incoming data from 3rd party

Tags: vb.net

I need to be able to create a web service so that when a third party sends me XML files I can save the file to a folder on the website to later be read by a filestream reader and written to a local MySql DB.  My issue is I want them to be able to transmit XML data without logging in, using credentials, etc.

I think I have to put the web service in the IIS7 manager as an application but I don't know what to write - to get it to save the file.

There was some code that came very close but I couldn't get it to work.

This is the code I have so far - and yes just a skeleton. But none of this can happen until I have the file saved. And I don't care about who sends XMLs in because if the first line isn't correct for the name it will get tossed.

Myorders.svc.vb

```
Imports System Imports System.IO 
Imports System.Xml 
Imports System.Text 
Imports System.Data

Public Class MyOrders

    Implements IMyOrders
    Public Shared OrderNo As String = ""

    Public Function ProcessOrder() Implements IMyOrders.ProcessOrder
        Dim filename As String = "" ' this would need to loop for any doc in the file. Grab JobOrder number as unique'
        Dim xdoc As New XmlDocument

        xdoc.Load(FileName)

        Return OrderNo
    End Function

    Private Sub IMyOrders_GetBuilder(OrderNum As String) Implements IMyOrders.GetBuilder
        Throw New NotImplementedException()
    End Sub

    Public Sub GetSuper(OrderNum As String) Implements IMyOrders.GetSuper
        Throw New NotImplementedException()
    End Sub

    Public Sub GetSuperPhone(OrderNum As String) Implements IMyOrders.GetSuperPhone
        Throw New NotImplementedException()
    End Sub

    Public Sub GetSuperEmail(OrderNum As String) Implements IMyOrders.GetSuperEmail
        Throw New NotImplementedException()
    End Sub

    Public Sub GetWorkType(OrderNum As String) Implements IMyOrders.GetWorkType
        Throw New NotImplementedException()
    End Sub

    Public Sub GetWorkAdd1(OrderNum As String) Implements IMyOrders.GetWorkAdd1
        Throw New NotImplementedException()
    End Sub

    Public Sub GetSubDiv(OrderNum As String) Implements IMyOrders.GetSubDiv
        Throw New NotImplementedException()
    End Sub

    Public Sub GetPhase(OrderNum As String) Implements IMyOrders.GetPhase
        Throw New NotImplementedException()
    End Sub

    Public Sub GetLot(OrderNum As String) Implements IMyOrders.GetLot
        Throw New NotImplementedException()
    End Sub

    Public Sub GetPlan(OrderNum As String) Implements IMyOrders.GetPlan
        Throw New NotImplementedException()
    End Sub

    Public Sub GetElevation(OrderNum As String) Implements IMyOrders.GetElevation
        Throw New NotImplementedException()
    End Sub

    Public Sub GetSwing(OrderNum As String) Implements IMyOrders.GetSwing
        Throw New NotImplementedException()
    End Sub

    Public Sub GetPermit(OrderNum As String) Implements IMyOrders.GetPermit
        Throw New NotImplementedException()
    End Sub

    Public Sub GetStartDate(OrderNum As String) Implements IMyOrders.GetStartDate
        Throw New NotImplementedException()
    End Sub

    Public Sub GetEndDate(OrderNum As String) Implements IMyOrders.GetEndDate
        Throw New NotImplementedException()
    End Sub

    Public Sub GetQuantity(OrderNum As String) Implements IMyOrders.GetQuantity
        Throw New NotImplementedException()
    End Sub

    Public Sub GetMonetary(OrderNum As String) Implements IMyOrders.GetMonetary
        Throw New NotImplementedException()
    End Sub

    Public Sub GetOptions(OrderNum As String) Implements IMyOrders.GetOptions
        Throw New NotImplementedException()
    End Sub

    Public Sub GetCommCode(OrderNum As String) Implements IMyOrders.GetCommCode
        Throw New NotImplementedException()
    End Sub

    Public Sub GetCommID(OrderNum As String) Implements IMyOrders.GetCommID
        Throw New NotImplementedException()
    End Sub
```

IMyOrders.vb

```
 Imports System.ServiceModel

' NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the context menu to change the interface name "IMyOrders" in both code and config file together.
<ServiceContract()>
Public Interface IMyOrders

    <OperationContract()>
    Function ProcessOrder()

    <OperationContract()>
    Sub GetBuilder(OrderNo As String)

    <OperationContract()>
    Sub GetSuper(OrderNo As String)

    <OperationContract()>
    Sub GetSuperPhone(OrderNo As String)

    <OperationContract()>
    Sub GetSuperEmail(OrderNo As String)

    <OperationContract()>
    Sub GetWorkType(OrderNo As String)

    <OperationContract()>
    Sub GetWorkAdd1(OrderNo As String)

    <OperationContract()>
    Sub GetSubDiv(OrderNo As String)

    <OperationContract()>
    Sub GetPhase(OrderNo As String)

    <OperationContract()>
    Sub GetLot(OrderNo As String)

    <OperationContract()>
    Sub GetPlan(OrderNo As String)

    <OperationContract()>
    Sub GetElevation(OrderNo As String)

    <OperationContract()>
    Sub GetSwing(OrderNo As String)

    <OperationContract()>
    Sub GetPermit(OrderNo As String)

    <OperationContract()>
    Sub GetStartDate(OrderNo As String)

    <OperationContract()>
    Sub GetEndDate(OrderNo As String)

    <OperationContract()>
    Sub GetQuantity(OrderNo As String)

    <OperationContract()>
    Sub GetMonetary(OrderNo As String)

    <OperationContract()>
    Sub GetOptions(OrderNo As String)

    <OperationContract()>
    Sub GetCommCode(OrderNo As String)

    <OperationContract()>
    Sub GetCommID(OrderNo As String)

End Interface
```

Comment: You created a WCF Service application if I'm not mistaken? Try creating a WCF Service Library, just 'create new' and hit start. See if the IIS express deployment it creates for you is good enough for development. You will of course need to deploy it later, and will run into all of the IIS issues then, but if you're this early on in development and are hitting this wall, I'd give the Library a try. It's much easier for learning.. It handles all of the leg work and uses the local IIS express to do the hard stuff for you. Then, when it's working, you can ask all the IIS questions..

Comment: when you get the test client, look for a line like this: http://localhost:8733/Design_Time_Addresses/WcfServiceLibrary1/Service1/mex .... use that to search in your real client app

Comment: Please read [ask] and take the [tour] and perhaps [mcve].  SO is for specific programming questions, not free consulting on application design.

Comment: If you don't require any authentication someone will eventually find your service and abuse it.